# Kubuntu: Second monitor not detected correctly

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

After a recent update, my second monitor is not detected correctly anymore. It is displays a copy of the first ones content.

Strange is that it appears to be detected correctly on the login screen: It has a different background image there. But when the login progress bar reaches about 70-80%, the first screen gets duplicated.

System Settings -> Hardware -> Display and Monitor -> Display Configuration is showing only the first monitor in the image, but the second one is available in the select field "Primary display".

I'm using an nvidia graphics card, if that is somehow important.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I unchecked the "Enabled" checkbox under "System Settings -> Hardware -> Display and Monitor -> Display Configuration" for one monitor and after rechecking it, the monitor reappeared next to the other one. So it's working again now.

Answer (score 3):

My solution steps below;

1. Connect hdmi cable
2. Write to terminal `xrandr -q`
3. Press the special button for extend monitor(<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> for lenovo series)
4. Choose extend options(For example "Extend to right") and press enter

Comment: What does `xrandr -q` do? It worked, but do I need to repeat this in the future?

Comment: xrandr is a command-line tool to interact with the X RandR extension which allows for live (re)configuration of the X server (i.e. without restarting it): It provides automatic discovery of modes (resolutions, refresh rates, etc.) together with the ability to configure outputs dynamically (resize, rotate, move, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Check what driver is being used.

If it says that there is a custom driver being used, open a terminal of your choice and run:

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.

Once completed, reboot by either selecting the Reboot option in the GNOME power menu or run `reboot` in the terminal.